# Format text in bluetooth printer

Tags: android, text, printing, bluetooth, format

actually, I have to implement a module the which connect to a BT termical printer and print in it. I have a simple but functionally example, it works with the printer. The problem is that these text are printed in plain text, and i have to give it format, bold, change the font size and others... How can i do it??. I don't know how... I use this Class:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.edec.aptr;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * This class does all the work for setting up and managing Bluetooth
 * connections with other devices. It has a thread that listens for incoming
 * connections, a thread for connecting with a device, and a thread for
 * performing data transmissions when connected.
 */
public class BluetoothService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothService";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME = "BTPrinter";

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); // change by
                                                                    // chongqing
                                                                    // jinou

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0; // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; // now listening for incoming
                                                // connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing
                                                    // connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; // now connected to a remote
                                                    // device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BTPrinter session.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler
     *            A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the connection
     * 
     * @param state
     *            An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(amarre.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1)
                .sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state.
     */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a session in
     * listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mAcceptThread == null) {
            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mAcceptThread.start();
        }
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * 
     * @param device
     *            The BluetoothDevice to connect
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * 
     * @param socket
     *            The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device
     *            The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket,
            BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "connected");

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one
        // device
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(amarre.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(amarre.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        setState(STATE_NONE);
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * 
     * @param out
     *            The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
                return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(amarre.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(
                amarre.TOAST,
                "No se puede conectar al dispostivo, verifique que éste se encuentra encendido y cercano a la tablet");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        // setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(amarre.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(amarre.TOAST,
                "La conexión con el dispositivo se ha perdido");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted (or
     * until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mAdapter
                        .listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D)
                Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate
                            // new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D)
                Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D)
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection with a
     * device. It runs straight through; the connection either succeeds or
     * fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG,
                            "unable to close() socket during connection failure",
                            e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device. It handles all
     * incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    if (bytes > 0) {
                        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(amarre.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1,
                                buffer).sendToTarget();
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected");
                        connectionLost();

                        // add by chongqing jinou
                        if (mState != STATE_NONE) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "disconnected");
                            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                            BluetoothService.this.start();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();

                    // add by chongqing jinou
                    if (mState != STATE_NONE) {
                        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                        BluetoothService.this.start();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * 
         * @param buffer
         *            The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(amarre.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I send the data from another class, so:

```
        byte[] send;
        try {
            send = message.getBytes("GB2312");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            send = message.getBytes();

        }

        mService.write(send);
```

message is a String var.. Then, how can I format the text??, or at least, change font size...

Comment: can you please provide full code,because I want to develop printer functionality in my application

Comment: U can giveme ur mail, i'll send u an example project, the which can print using an ESC/POS thermal printer...

Comment: hi leonardo. please send me the project too. to aarbiyech@gmail.com

Comment: Where do you get the variable ammare? Would you please end me the same code to do printing through bluetooth? I need to do the same for my application. Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Now I know how to do it. I had to apply reverse engineering and de-compile an .apk from the  market, using dex2jar on Linux and then opening the jar with java de-compiler... Try this...When you write this command:

`out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);`

you are sending to the method a byte[] array. You can modify the format by sending another byte[] array before sending the real byte[] array...

The default format byte[] array is this:

`byte[] arrayOfByte1 = { 27, 33, 0 };`

So u can try this:

```
byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

out.write(format);

out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
```

These lines will print the default format text, but if you try below code,

```
byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

format[2] = ((byte)(0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

out.write(format);

out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
```

it will print text in bold style... You can try these other format arrays:

```
// Bold
format[2] = ((byte)(0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

// Height
format[2] = ((byte)(0x10 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

// Width
format[2] = ((byte) (0x20 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

// Underline
format[2] = ((byte)(0x80 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

// Small
format[2] = ((byte)(0x1 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
```

Also you can combine it, then if you like little and bold text, uncomment these array assignments, for example:

```
byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

// Bold
format[2] = ((byte)(0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
// Height
format[2] = ((byte)(0x10 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
// Width
format[2] = ((byte) (0x20 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
// Underline
// format[2] = ((byte)(0x80 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
// Small
// format[2] = ((byte)(0x1 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
out.write(format);
out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
```

This last code prints que biggest text size.

Comment: How do you remove the bold setting? For example, you use bold format and print a line, how do you unbold the next line without resending a new string. I want it to be one straight command.

Comment: Nevermind that I got it, just write `format[2] = ((byte)(0x0 | arrayOfByte1[2])); `

Comment: U're forced to resend the bytearray, if you set the bold to the printer, you should send again the init array: ` byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };`

Comment: any way to print straight lines? and set gravity of the text?

Comment: Staright Lines?, like that? ________________________________

Comment: Just wanted to say Leonardo you are great !

Comment: @LeonardoSapuy Any idea of alignment of text in center and right.

Comment: @LeonardoSapuy I'm unable to do the format combination, if I do small & bold, result is bold only. If I do bold & small, result is small only. Is it possible that it's the printer's limitation?

Comment: Is there anyway to set font type ttf on text?

Comment: This is very OK for me. Thanks. Is it possible with some code set width and height of tekst ?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old thread but it helped me alot so I decided to share my code for simplified use of Formatting.

Sample usage:

```
final String message = "Example message\n";
// Default format:
writeWithFormat(message.getBytes(), new Formatter().get(), Formatter.leftAlign());
// Bold format center:
writeWithFormat(message.getBytes(), new Formatter().bold().get(), Formatter.centerAlign());
// Bold underlined format with right alignment:
writeWithFormat(message.getBytes(), new Formatter().bold().underlined().get(), Formatter.rightAlign());
```

Formatter class with Builder pattern:

```
/**
 * Class for formatting
 */
public static class Formatter {
    /** The format that is being build on */
    private byte[] mFormat;

    public Formatter() {
        // Default:
        mFormat = new byte[]{27, 33, 0};
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the Build result
     *
     * @return the format
     */
    public byte[] get() {
        return mFormat;
    }

    public Formatter bold() {
        // Apply bold:
        mFormat[2] = ((byte) (0x8 | mFormat[2]));
        return this;
    }

    public Formatter small() {
        mFormat[2] = ((byte) (0x1 | mFormat[2]));
        return this;
    }

    public Formatter height() {
        mFormat[2] = ((byte) (0x10 | mFormat[2]));
        return this;
    }

    public Formatter width() {
        mFormat[2] = ((byte) (0x20 | mFormat[2]));
        return this;
    }

    public Formatter underlined() {
        mFormat[2] = ((byte) (0x80 | mFormat[2]));
        return this;
    }

    public static byte[] rightAlign(){
        return new byte[]{0x1B, 'a', 0x02};
    }

    public static byte[] leftAlign(){
        return new byte[]{0x1B, 'a', 0x00};
    }

    public static byte[] centerAlign(){
        return new byte[]{0x1B, 'a', 0x01};
    }
}
```

The write method that uses the formatting looks like this:

```
     /**
     * Method to write with a given format
     *
     * @param buffer     the array of bytes to actually write
     * @param pFormat    The format byte array
     * @param pAlignment The alignment byte array
     * @return true on successful write, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean writeWithFormat(byte[] buffer, final byte[] pFormat, final byte[] pAlignment) {
        try {
            // Notify printer it should be printed with given alignment:
            mOutputStream.write(pAlignment);
            // Notify printer it should be printed in the given format:
            mOutputStream.write(pFormat);
            // Write the actual data:
            mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            App.getInstance().getHandler().obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, buffer.length, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Koen it is working but sometime alignment doesn't work. Am i missing something?. Like i have set alignment on text center but it align left. Any idea?

Comment: @Sumit Kumar Are you trying to print something like:
"Left text"  "Centered Text"  "Right Text" on one line? (Like 3 columns in 1 row)

Comment: how to make text bigger than default?

Comment: @UsmanRana Raha writeWithFormat(message.getBytes(), new Formatter().height().get(), Formatter.leftAlign());

Not all printers support it tho

Comment: Is there anyway to set font type ttf on text?

Comment: @Koen I want to print "Left Text" and "Right Text" in one line, please guide me if it is possible

Comment: @Aditya Rohilla That is indeed possible by using left aligned text and adding an x amount of spaces. Based on the text size  and printer type, different amount of spaces should be added. For my printer its 42 characters with the small font option and 32  characters if the normal font is used

Answer (score 2):

There are two perceptions to this:

> you are just trying to print by passing the text. You are leaving option to the printer to choose to print anyway it wants.
>
> check whether your printer supports Basic Printing Profile[BPP] - Job Based Transfer. I had success printing it in html format, both images and text on a bluetooth printer.

Also, check for the UUID you are providing. They are different UUID for Object push profile, BPP Job Based Transfer profile. I suggest you use the UUID assiged for BPP[Job based transfer]
and try passing a xhtml file with formatted text.

Thanks
Mani