# How print invoice receipt using bluetooth thermal printer

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, thermal-printer

I have to print invoice receipt using thermal printer.
I have used [Zjiang Thermal printer](http://www.zjiang.com/product.asp?cat_id=26&name=&class_id=74) to print receipt.
They also provide there [manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77sjXvrRR-_WVA1Rnh0a0QtYTA/view?usp=sharing) & demo project.
In demo project they use a libray "btsdk.jar" to implement connection & print.

I have successfully establish connection between printer & android device.
But there is no guideline for **text alignment (center, left, right) & cell width, height.**

I   [have try it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285822/format-text-in-bluetooth-printer). It only change text height by changing format[2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77sjXvrRR-_WVA1Rnh0a0QtYTA/view?usp=sharing) variable.

**How I print invoice by bluetooth printer.**

**please also explain this section-**

```
 byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
 cmd[0] = 0x1b;
 cmd[1] = 0x21;
 cmd[2] |= 0x10;
```

cmd[2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77sjXvrRR-_WVA1Rnh0a0QtYTA/view?usp=sharing) - used for change font height
what is use of cmd[0] & cmd[1](http://www.zjiang.com/product.asp?cat_id=26&name=&class_id=74)

**code to send Printing message to bluetooth Printer In Demo Project**

```
 String msg = "";
 byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
 cmd[0] = 0x1b;
 cmd[1] = 0x21;
 cmd[2] |= 0x10;
 mService.write(cmd);           
 mService.sendMessage("Congratulations!\n", "GBK"); 
 cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
 mService.write(cmd);          
 msg = "  You have sucessfully created communications between your device and our bluetooth printer.\n\n"
      +"  the company is a high-tech enterprise which specializes" +
        " in R&D,manufacturing,marketing of thermal printers and barcode scanners.\n\n";
 mService.sendMessage(msg,"GBK");
```

**Print Info-**

```
       parameters:support to download the Logo trademark
       FontA:12*24 dots,1.5(W)*3.0(H) mm
       FontB:9*17 dots, 1.1(W)*2.1(H) mm
       Simplified/Traditional: 24*24 dots, 3.0(W)*3.0(H)
       Line spacing: 3.75mm (Default)
       Barcode Types:-
       1D Barcode- UPC-A/UPC-E, JAN13(EAN13), JAN8(EAN8), CODE39/ITF, CODABAR,CODE93
       2d Barcode- QR CODE
```

**Invoice Receipt**

[image]

Comment: from where i can download this SDK??

Comment: prog manual is here http://www.issyzonepos.com/uploadfile/downloads/58MMPrinter%20Programmer%20Manual-20150312.pdf

Comment: Have you succesfully printed the reciept ??

Comment: how to print left and right align in same row ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the following image over the internet for Text Alignment. Hope it helps

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works for text alignment.I have get a set of commands https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/Driver%20board.pdf Can u suggest for print data in Table format.

Comment: I haven't found for anything related to table, you have to build table using the standard commands.

Comment: As in details section, the command is enabled only when processed at the beginning of the line in standard mode. We can't provide multiple alignment for one line. we set alignment for line.Then how we print  one letter left & other right in one line.

Comment: did you find a way to print bold text?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo no, not yet. In fact I haven't look into it since then.

Comment: read the following answer, hope it helps in "bold" the text http://stackoverflow.com/a/15981715/1061944

Comment: how to increase the font size ? i want to write little bigger than before

Comment: refer to device sdk documentation

Comment: I can't understand how to use these commands pls help its urgent

Comment: Every thermal printer comes with its instruction set to print data on the thermal paper. Instruction depends on which printer you are using.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
void printLine(String txt, char type){
    byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };
    byte[] arrayOfByte1 = { 27, 33, 0 };

    if (type == 'b') {
        format[2] = ((byte) (0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2])); //BOLD
    }
    if (type == 'h') {
        format[2] = ((byte) (0x10 | arrayOfByte1[2])); //HEIGHT
    }
    if (type == 'w') {
        format[2] = ((byte) (0x20 | arrayOfByte1[2])); //WIDTH
    }
    if (type == 'u') {
        format[2] = ((byte) (0x80 | arrayOfByte1[2])); //UNDERLINE
    }
    if (type == 's') {
        format[2] = ((byte) (0x1 | arrayOfByte1[2])); //SMALL
    }
    mService.write(format);
    mService.sendMessage(txt,"GBK");
}
```

credit goes to Leonardo Sapuy and his original q/a [Format text in bluetooth printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285822/format-text-in-bluetooth-printer/15981715#15981715)
and thanks to Murtaza Khursheed Hussain for sending me to it