# Underline command for datamini 58mm,384 points/lines bluetooth printer for android

Tags: android, thermal-printer, bluetooth-printing

i'm trying to print out some text with my datamini printer.i want to print full horizontal underline.firstly i'm following this guide from blue bamboo(though its different company but m not getting guide of datamini):
http://www.londatiga.net/downloads/P25_Development_Guide_V3.9(2012-12-31).pdf

and secondly i've been trying with these:

```
        String test2="sometext";
        byte[] arrayOfByte1 = { 0x27, 0x33, 0x00 };
        byte[] format = { 0x27, 0x33, 0x00 };

        format[2] = ((byte)(0x80 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

        mmOutputStream.write(format);
        mmOutputStream.write(test2.getBytes(),0,test2.getBytes().length);
```

which i pulled out from [Format text in bluetooth printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285822/format-text-in-bluetooth-printer/15981715#15981715)

Answer (score 0):

i could not get the actual code for my answer. but i've managed some how by writing some --------- where i need underline.